# Getting unexpected token ILLEGAL error for server.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm going through the node.js in action book and I'm currently trying to build the chat based application on the second chapter. However, I keep on getting the Unexpected token ILLEGAL when I try to run the HTTP server, but i don't seem to see anything wrong:

```
var http  = require('http');
var fs    = require('fs');
var path  = require('path');
var mime  = require('mime');
var cache = {};

function send404(response) {
  response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Error 404: resource not found.');
  response.end();
}

function sendFile(response, filePath, fileContents) {
  response.writeHead(
    200,
    {"content-type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath))}
  );
    response.end(fileContents);
  }

function serveStatic(response, cache, absPath) {
  if (cache[absPath]) {
    sendFile(response, absPath, cache[absPath]);
  } 
  else {
    fs.exists(absPath, function(exists) {
      if (exists) {
        fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            send404(response);
          } 
          else {
            cache[absPath] = data;
            sendFile(response, absPath, data);
          }
              });
         } 
      else {
        send404(response);
      }
    }); 
   }
}
  ￼
￼var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var filePath = false;
  if (request.url == '/') {
    filePath = 'public/index.html';
  } 
  else {
    filePath = 'public' + request.url;
  }
  var absPath = './' + filePath;
  serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
￼  console.log("Server listening on port 3000.");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have strange hidden characters in your code, 
try this

```
var http  = require('http');
var fs    = require('fs');
var path  = require('path');
var mime  = require('mime');
var cache = {};

function send404(response) {
  response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Error 404: resource not found.');
  response.end();
}

function sendFile(response, filePath, fileContents) {
  response.writeHead(
    200,
    {"content-type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath))}
  );
    response.end(fileContents);
  }

function serveStatic(response, cache, absPath) {
  if (cache[absPath]) {
    sendFile(response, absPath, cache[absPath]);
  }
  else {
    fs.exists(absPath, function(exists) {
      if (exists) {
        fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            send404(response);
          }
          else {
            cache[absPath] = data;
            sendFile(response, absPath, data);
          }
              });
         }
      else {
        send404(response);
      }
    });
   }
}

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var filePath = false;
  if (request.url == '/') {
    filePath = 'public/index.html';
  }
  else {
    filePath = 'public' + request.url;
  }
  var absPath = './' + filePath;
  serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000.");
});
```